# how can I move pictures from a jtable to another one then rotate them?

Tags: java, image, swing, jtable

I'm doing the Eternity(puzzle) game 
I made 2 jtables in the first one I charged pictures of the pieces.  In the second one I'm supposed to move the pieces from the first jtable.  I have to use drag and drop to move those pictures and then,  I have to rotate them in the second jtable to get the coherent pictures.  What should I do?

Comment: Use `setDragEnabled` on components you want to be draggable. Then take a look at the `TransferHandler` API to implement how the receiving JTable will handle the incoming image

Comment: Thank you i have another question the TransfertHandler must be in the 2nd jtable or the 1st one ( the one that contain the pieces to move)?

Comment: whichever is the 'receiver', so the second table I suppose. But you could write one table class and use it for both your tables -- then both tables would be able to receive dragged items!

Comment: i found this short walkthrough, it might be helpful: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/draganddrop/